# replace something in a particular field of a splited file bash shell

Tags: bash, file, shell, awk, edit

i am trying to access a field of a file with the following form

```
F1|F2|F3|F4|F5|F6|F7|F8
```

user will give me the command:

> ./tool.sh -f file --edit id column value

**tool.sh** is the name of the codefile, **id** is the first field **column** is the column where the value needs to be replaced **value** is the string i have to replace (F1) and i will have to scan the file find where id matches and when i find the correct line need to go to the right column (which will be given by the user) and replace the F(column) with the **value**. 
here is one of my thoughts:

```
awk -v id="$4" -v column = "$5" -v value = "$6" -F"|" 
'BEGIN{OFS="|"} ($1 == id){$(column)=value;}'  $2
```

where i will set the values in awk and use them in it but i get

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `=' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

i am new in bash shell and you maybe see big mistakes

Comment: ./tool.sh -f persons.txt --edit 933 2 stringtobereplaced

Answer (score 0):

in `bash` spaces matter.  There shouldn't be white space surrounding `=` signs in your variable declarations.  Change it to:

```
awk -F'|' -v id="$4" -v column="$5" -v value="$6" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $1==id{$column=value}' $2
```

Comment: you are right i corrected it but i dont get the expected result tha file remains the same

Comment: input file won't change, check the output generated.

Answer (score 0):

file content :

```
F1|F2|F3|F4|F5|F6|F7|F8
G1|G2|G3|G4|G5|G6|G7|G8
H1|H2|H3|H4|H5|H6|H7|H8
```

script shell tool.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh
params=$*
file_to_use=`echo $params | sed -e "s/ -/\n-/g" |  sed -n "s/^-f  *\(.*\)/\1/p"`
field_to_edit=`echo $params |  sed -e "s/ -/\n-/g" | sed -n "s/^--edit  *\(.*\)/\1/p"`

if [ "$file_to_use" != "" ] && [ -f $file_to_use ] && [ "`echo $field_to_edit | grep -E "^[0-9]+$"`" != "" ]; then
 cat $file_to_use | cut -d"|" -f$field_to_edit
else
 echo " Error of parameters"
fi
```

test :

```
 ./tool.sh -f non_exist_file --edit 5
 Error of parameters

 ./tool.sh -f file --edit x
 Error of parameters

 ./tool.sh -f file --edit 6
F6
G6
H6
```